# Aws emr using hdfs as storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

I have a question  aws emr cluster.

We have an EMR cluster with 42 nodes where HDFS is used as a distributed data storage(input).The spark jobs would use this hdfs data for transformations and store it in s3. We do not have auto scaling turned on yet and all 42 are always up and running even at lower workloads .

Can enabling auto scaling cause loosing the hdfs data ie the source of input ?
When the cluster is used by smaller jobs we do not need at 42 nodes running at the same time we need hdfs data to be available.

Comment: Why not use EMRFS instead of HDFS? That's how you are usually address the storage persistency issue on EMR?

Comment: Thanks, my question was, If we enable autoscaling will we lose the data in HDFS in EMR, specifically at lower workloads?